# Populate a div with an image using Javascript from database

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firestore for my database and looking to populate my HTML with the details I receive from it.
Below is the connection and javascript method that populates my HTML:

```
  db.collection("Ingredients2").where("Category", "==", 
0).get().then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
         //get database information
          const price = doc.data().Price;
          const name = doc.data().Name;
          const id = doc.data().IngredientID;
          const image = doc.data().Photo;


        //create elements
          var button = document.createElement("button");
          button.className = "imgButton";
          var divbunname = document.createElement("bunname" + id);
          divbunname.className = "imgName";
          var divbunimage = document.createElement("bunimage" + id);
          divbunimage.className = "imgPicture";
          var divbunprice = document.createElement("bunprice" + id);
          divbunprice.className = "imgPrice";
          var image1 = document.createElement("img" + id);
          image1.className = "imgPicture img";


          divbunprice.innerHTML = price;
          divbunname.innerHTML = name;
          image1.src = image;

          document.getElementById("bunstab").appendChild(button);
          button.appendChild(divbunname);
          button.appendChild(divbunimage);
          divbunimage.appendChild(image1);
          button.appendChild(divbunprice);

        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
```

This populates the name and price but the image does not appear. This is my css:

```
.imgButton {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  background-color: rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.541);
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.imgName {}

.imgPicture {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-size: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: pink solid;
  float none;
}

.imgPicture img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  outline: green solid;
}
```

Any ideas on why the image is not showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem

```
var image1 = document.createElement("img" + id);
```

you are trying to add **id** to a native **createElement()** method and hence browser doesn't recognize it as an image element, for example browser is expecting something like `<img></img>` tag to render image but it getting something like `<img123></img123>` so images are not showing up in an unknown tag. You have to create it like

```
    var image1 = document.createElement("img");
```

if you want to add id to any element, you can add it separately like

```
    var image1.id = id;
```

hope it'll help.